# Taking screen shot from a background app programatically in iOS 8 using a private api but on "non jailbroken" device

Tags: ios, screenshot, iphone-privateapi, ios8.1

Is there a way to take a screenshot when the app is in the background. I saw to the questions

[Releasing an IOSurface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952313/releasing-an-iosurface)

[Taking Screenshots in the background (iOS) - Improving Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971013/taking-screenshots-in-the-background-ios-improving-performance)

And i could not figure out whether those answers were for a jailbroken device and also from where did they get the IOSurface framework. I tried to implement the code and failed to do so. So my question is that. Is it possible to take a screenshot when the app is in background in iOS 8 using private framework but should be possible to run on non jailbroken devices. If so can anyone help.

Comment: Is there a difference from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically

Comment: @banshee_walk_sly yes ofcourse. Using that approach u can't take a screenshot from a background app.

Comment: Ok, just checking. Carry on then.