# Is UIGetScreenImage() function removed in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, cydia, tweak

Before `iOS7` I use `UIGetScreenImage()` to take screenshot of the entire screen at any view of the `iOS`, not only inside my tweak app but also views of other apps.

In `iOS7`, when I use this function I got `implicit declaration of function` error, then I added a prototype in the code as blow, this error disappeared, but got  `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64` error. It looks like 'UIGetScreenImage' has been deleted in iOS7, is it? If so, what can I do to replace it?

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
```

Comment: `UIGetScreenImage` was exposed briefly because of the accidental approval of a hit app that used it and a general sense of unfairness that followed; it became private API again in iOS 6. Even if you use it under 6 you're likely to get a rejection.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see UIGetScreenImage() in Apple's documentation. For iOS 7 there's a new method:

`-[UIScreen snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:]` -- see the [UIScreen](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScreen/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates%3a)  documentation.

Similarly, there is a `-[UIView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:]` method -- see the [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates%3a) documentation.

Comment: This method can only be used in my app, but I want to take screenshot for any view including other apps.In fact, my app is a tweak inside `SpringBoard`.

Answer (score 1):

This private API function was removed from the iOS 7 64-bit SDK but still exists in the 32-bit version. I just ran it via the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIGetScreenImage()` is removed in IOS 7.

You can use the following for screenshot purposes:

[snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates%3a)

[drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect%3aafterScreenUpdates%3a):

[resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/resizableSnapshotViewFromRect%3aafterScreenUpdates%3awithCapInsets%3a)

Comment: This method can only be used in my app, but I want to take screenshot for any view including other apps.In fact, my app is a tweak inside `SpringBoard`.

Comment: You might want to check the following discussion:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833816/taking-screenshots-from-ios-app-emulating-display-recorder-query-on-the-inter