# Code works properly on simulator but doesnt work on my iphone.Can anybody help me please?

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak

```
On iOS6:

void (*BKSDisplayServicesSetScreenBlanked)(BOOL blanked) = (void (*)(BOOL blanked))dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "BKSDisplayServicesSetScreenBlanked");

and then use:

BKSDisplayServicesSetScreenBlanked(1); // 1 to dim, 0 to undim
```

And I dont care if my app would be rejected by the appstore

Comment: what version of iOS is the device running?

Comment: i think it has something to do with the permissions

Comment: I don't know your exat problem but see this post perhaps it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950194/turn-off-display-in-iphone-os-ios

Comment: @Vishal I've seen this post vishal.But I dont know how to set the entitlements

Comment: Here's a post that talks specifically about setting entitlements in a jailbreak environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069330/ios-how-to-use-entitlement-plist-to-specify-property-of-my-app