# Turning off the iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-brightness

The only way I could find to programmatically turn off (not just dim) the iPhone's screen was by utilizing the `UIDevice` property `proximityMonitoringEnabled`, which will automatically turn off the screen if the infrared sensor detects proximity to an object while enabled.

Any other (public API only) methods for this? Any way to achieve a reverse-proximity effect (the screen dims when *not* proximal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am inclined to say no. Not by using a Public API. I believe that the only way to do this would be to use your method `proximityMonitoringEnabled`.

There was a way to use a Private API in iOS 5, but it appears that it does not work for iOS 6. ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944387/2535467) covers iOS 5).

Your best bet is to use the `proximityMonitoringEnable` and `proximityState`.