# iOS Turn off screen iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, api

Is there any way to turn off screen and adjust volume on the iPad programmatically? It can be private api as this is for personal use. I know that in iPhone you can use proximity sensor but I don't suppose this method would work on iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `proximityMonitoringEnabled` and `proximityState` to handle screen. Look at comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1191675/67381) answer.

And there is no way to adjust volume

From [developer.apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html)

> Global system volume, including your application's volume, is handled
>   by iPhone OS and is not accessible by applications.

Comment: Will proximity sensor work on iPad Hugh since it doesn't use it? And in regards to volume there must be an api for Apple to use even if private. I don't think apple would hand code that each time they need it rather than just create api and make it private

Comment: Did you try it? I tried to enable monitor and set proximityState, but it doesn't work (at least on iOS 6)