# Turn off mobile screen in HTML5 web application

Tags: android, ios, html

I wrote an HTML5 web application which is intended to run for a long time (on Android and iOS).
I would like to lower the battery consumption by turning off the display without locking the phone.
Is it possible to achieve this functionality using a web application or only by using a native application?

Thanks,
Buenon

Comment: In iOS, you can't turn off the screen by Web / Native Application ( except for Private API or deprecated methods. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950194/turn-off-display-in-iphone-os-ios )

Comment: See also this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189895/turning-screen-off